# You have an error in your SQL syntax; near 'SET `points` = `points` + ?'

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I'm getting this error, which seems like it should be easy to find, but no matter how much I look at the code, or Google it, I can't figure it out.

Here is the code

```
INSERT INTO `users` (`username`)
    VALUES (?)
        ON DUPLICATE KEY
            UPDATE `users` SET `points` = `points` + ?
```

The ? are later given values using prepared statements, however for testing I replaced them with actual values like below

```
INSERT INTO `users` (`username`)
    VALUES (`existingusername`)
        ON DUPLICATE KEY
            UPDATE `users` SET `points` = `points` + 5
```

And I also tried `nonextistingusername` as a value. And I tried using `WHERE` for `UPDATE` but believe it isn't needed because I'm using `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`

I don't see where I'm going wrong here

Edit: I also tried brackets around the "`points` + 5"

Edit: further code

```
foreach ($users as $user)
{
    $points_query = mysqli_prepare($db, 'INSERT INTO `users` (`username`)
        VALUES (?)
            ON DUPLICATE KEY
                UPDATE `users` SET (`points` = `points` + ?)');

    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($points_query, 'si', $user, $user_points);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($points_query);

    echo mysqli_error($db) . "\n";
}
```

And the SQL error

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax;
check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL
server version for the right syntax to
use near 'SET (`points` = `points` + ?)' at line 4
```

Comment: Can you add the PHP code and the error message to the question?

Comment: @chris85 I have updated it. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct syntax does not use the table name again or the keyword `SET`.

```
ON DUPLICATE KEY
   UPDATE `points` = `points` + ?
```

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-on-duplicate.html

Comment: thank you. had a feeling it would be related to using `ON DUPLICATE KEY` and must have overlooked the change in the query